# How to get a Google Streetview in pano mode?

Tags: google-street-view, panoramas

I recently came across many sites showing a Google streetview in panoramic mode, like this one: http://jackiedu.com/aprg/list/mypropdet.aspx?sid=100081&pid=706831, in the right bottom you will see it.

How was that generated? Google? or by the website itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript API for google maps has a panoramic mode. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewPanorama

Comment: The pano keeps spining, is there a widget to present this? Thanks.

Comment: No. It is just a javascript timer. See the source of this page http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/streetview/streetview_lazy.html for a howto.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how can I use it in my wordpress page?